# Show 1 Cell of data as list in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

i have database table 'jobs' where there`s description and requirement column.

Each description and column can have several value in the cell separated by an "enter"

how can i show the data in laravel blade as a lists?

This is my blade

```
<ul class="lst">
    <li class="it">
        <input class="ipt-hidden" name="tabs-1" type="radio" id="tab1" checked>
        <label class="title twomenu" for="tab1">JOB DESCRIPTIONS</label>
        <div class="wrp-content">
            <ul class="show-item">
                <li>{{ $jobs->description }}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="it">
        <input class="ipt-hidden" name="tabs-1" type="radio" id="tab2">
        <label class="title twomenu" for="tab2">REQUIREMENTS</label>
        <div class="wrp-content">
            <ul class="show-item">
                <li>{{ $jobs->requirement }}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>

</ul>
```

What i want is the jobs requirements & descriptions can show as several list, can i do that?
because what i get is just 1 list separated by spacing.

Thankyou all :)

Comment: Use `@foreach` of laravel.

Comment: Separating by enter is bad practice. Put in database data in JSON format. Then u can use foreach. Remember to serializa data before putting to database and unserialize when getting from database. Thats is requirement for json. Cheers!

Comment: thankyou guys for the answer, ill try change the format to json first then.